# ADF using sinked cache in Source?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have sinked data to cache in Azure Data Factory Mapping Dataflow and would like to use data from sink in the Container and Wildcardpath of a new Source. Is that possible?

[image]

In the source I have tried to add SourceExpressionCache#outputs()[1].SourceDirectory to the Container:

[image]

Error :

```
Spark job failed: {
"text/plain": "{\"runId\":\"74358980-da2a-490e-b193-352c20fb48e3\",\"sessionId\":\"920b092c-3def-4850-b4d4-5e87e64c4619\",\"status\":\"Failed\",\"payload\":{\"statusCode\":400,\"shortMessage\":\"DF-DRAFT_001 at Source 'GenericDocument'(Line 21/Col 0): Unresolved specification\",\"detailedMessage\":\"Failure 2022-03-17 06:52:57.757 failed DebugManager.processJob, run=74358980-da2a-490e-b193-352c20fb48e3, errorMessage=DF-DRAFT_001 at Source 'GenericDocument'(Line 21/Col 0): Unresolved specification\"}}\n"
} - RunId: 74358980-da2a-490e-b193-352c20fb48e3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reproed using Cache sink with sample data. Please see the below steps.

1. In the Cache sink setting do not provide the Key columns when you are using the **output()** function of the Cached lookup.

[image]

mapping:

[image]

2. In the new source, I am passing the cache output as folder/directory to read the new file.
3. In the expression builder, cached lookup allows using 2 functions **lookup()** and **outputs()**.

> [outputs()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder#cached-lookup) takes no parameters and returns the entire cache sink as an array of complex columns. This can't be called if key columns are specified in the sink and should only be used if there is a small number of rows in the cache sink.

Expression:  `sink1#outputs()[1].Value`

[image]

[image]

Output: New source reads data from the folder of Cache sink value.

[image]